# NextGen Nivoslider (Wordpress): Image Resize

Tags: resize, nivo-slider, nextgen-gallery

I have the plugin working on a slideshow of images here:

http://samsweet.info/

I've uploaded all the images at the desired full size; all fall within 600 X 500 px. If I don't specify the height/width in the shortcode, the images are stretched and blown out to fill the entire content area. But when I specify the height and width in the shortcode, the images are not responsive and do not "shrink down" when the window is resized. Can someone guide me on how to get these images to (a) show up as they are at full size, centered and (b) resize properly in a smaller window/mobile device?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does anyone have insight into this issue? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your slider is wrapped in a div, try just resizing the div with css. That way your images will keep their aspect ratio, but you can still use percentages (and max-width).

```
.slider-div{
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Megan! Unfortunately, I can't seem to make it work. Either the images still aren't resizing, or the center alignment goes off... do you know enough about the nivoslider shortcodes to suggest what might be making this happen? This is the code on the page as of now:

Comment: `<div align="center">[ngg-nivoslider gallery="4" order="random" pausetime="150000" width="600"  height="500" resize="3"   controlnav="false" randomstart="true" center="1" directionnav="false" keyboardnav="false" manualadvance="true" shuffle="true"]</div>`

Comment: Hmm, I've never used the shortcodes, but have you tried adding width="100%" and height="100%"? Then you should be able to change the size of your containing div, and add a margin: auto if you need it

Answer (score 0):

This boggled my mind for a year and today I finally figured it out. It is the transition that is stretched. When I changed it to effect="none" it still worked and no more stretching. But the quick click buttons below the images no longer work. Ahhh...always something. But there's a clue at least.